# How to refresh an image with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, image, data-binding, refresh

I need to refresh an image that I load like this:

```html
<img [src]="linkPicture" alt="profile photo" width="150px" height="150px">
```

Into the typescript file I have a variable this.linkPicture that I store initially the link. When I update the picture don't refresh. I set the variable again....

Here is part of my typescript code

```
public linkPicture          : string;
```

Set the variable initially

```
this.service.GetProfile(id).subscribe(resp => {
        .....
        this.linkPicture = resp.Photo;
        console.log(resp); //this show the photo
    });
```

When I update the picture

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogUploadPhotoComponent, {
        data: {
            patientID: this.ss.getCurrentUserApi().PatientID
        },
        width : "550px",
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            if(result != undefined){
                console.log(result);
                this.linkPicture = result;   //I set the new picture.                   
            }
        });
```

Comment: How are you updating the picture? Do you mean you're update the link / content of the link?

Comment: yes of course, I get the new link into the response of a service and set the variable.

Comment: It would be better if you can show us some code.. that would help answerer to pin point exactly where you're missing things

Comment: I'm going to guess that you're updating the image on the server side and that the URL remains the same. If this is not the case, let me know and I'll remove my answer.

Comment: Yes i update the image on API, I get the response ok with the new link of the image. It's look like a cache don't update. I don't know what happen.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can append a timestamp query to the image URL to force the browser to reload the image. This shouldn't have any negative side effects with the server hosting the image.

Update the template to call a function:

```
<img [src]="getLinkPicture()" alt="profile photo" width="150px" height="150px">
```

Compute the URL using an optional timeStamp value:

```
public getLinkPicture() {
     if(this.timeStamp) {
        return this.linkPicture + '?' + this.timeStamp;
     }
     return this.linkPicture;
}
```

When the URL is changed. Create a new timeStamp value.

```
public setLinkPicture(url: string) {
     this.linkPicture = url;
     this.timeStamp = (new Date()).getTime();
}
```

Even if the URL is the same the timestamp changes, and this forces the browser to reload the image.

Comment: you saved my life, I tried generating a new sanitized URL but somehow on ionic+android it did not work

Comment: Using the function directly will cause it to run repeatedly, just add a console log and you'll see. With a lot of elements on the page this will have an impact on performance. Instead, try using a reference to a field instead of a function and setting the value in the initialization stage of the component in which this element sits.

Comment: However, of course, having it run repeatedly is what is allowing your feature to work, albeit at a very high processing cost.

Comment: @SimonDever you are right,  it is running repeatedly, showing net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this. at least I solve liked this

*on your .ts file*

```
export class MainLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
public isDesktopDevice: boolean = true;
public sidebarBackgroundClass!: string;


public sideBarOpen: boolean = true; // *sidebar is open by default
}

ngOnInit(): void {
if (this.isDesktopDevice) { this.sidebarBackgroundClass = this.getLayoutBackground(); 
}

public getLayoutBackground(): string {
const bgs: string[] = [
  'side1-1',
  'side1-2',
  'side2-1',
  'side2-2',
];

const max = bgs.length;
const min = 0;
const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
const bgClass = bgs[index];
return bgClass;
```

then add photos to your css file one by one like this:

*.css*

```
.side1-1{ background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),url('/assets/images/side/side1.1.jpg') !important;}
```

the final add class to your html:

```
<mat-drawer [class]="sidebarBackgroundClass"></mat-drawer>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  backgroundImageGenerate()
    {
        var myVar = setInterval(() => {
        this.imageApi();
                   
        console.log(this.isStatusCode);

        if (this.isStatusCode.indexOf(true) - 1) {
            clearInterval(myVar);
        }
        }, 15000)
    }
```

```
generateImage(){
        this.campaignsService.generateImage(this.params.id).subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.backgroundImageGenerate();
        }, (error) => {
            this.notify.error('Something went wrong');
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

```
<button type="button" (click)="generateImage()" mat-raised-button color="primary"
      [title]="'ADD_CAMPAIGN_PRODUCT' | translate:lang" style="margin:5px;">
      <i class="material-icons">add_circle</i>{{ 'GENERATE_IMAGE' | translate:lang }}
</button>
```